# windows 10 taskbar right click only have "close window" or "unpin from taskbar"

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

i am using **windows 10**, When i right click program icon on taskbar, the only option is "**Close all windows**" while the program is running, Or "**Unpin from taskbar**" while the program is pinned but not running. how can i solve this problem? even all of the questions on stackexchange site are not relevant to my question.

**2 screenshots below are expected**(there are 3 options and Recent jump list):

[image]

[image]

but i just have "Close all windows" or "Unpin from taskbar". How can i get other options back?

Comment: Sounds like normal behavior. What is the expected result? Which program does it happen with? Where is it installed? (program files, network share, etc)

Comment: Is what you are looking for found by pressing shift while right-clicking?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question correctly, given that you haven't actually mentioned what you expect to see, so I have to do a little bit of guess work here.

I think you are missing the `unpin program from taskbar` option while the program is running. This is typically the case if the pinned program is not the same as the program that is actually running. It is possible the pinned program is a shortcut or batch script that was added by using a hack, or is pinned using a group policy by your sysadmins.

If it happened overnight, then it is likely the program got updated.

In either case, you can try the following:
Close the program, unpin the icon, start the program, pin the icon.

Small warning: You cannot pin programs that reside on a network share, so it is very well possible that you unpin the program, but are not able to pin it back again.

Comment: i mean the only option was "unpin from taskbar" while the program is NOT running. And the only option was "close window" while the program is running.

Comment: i have updated the question to let it be clear.

Comment: Can you unpin the program while closed, then start it and see if the options are there? If that works, then pin it again and see if that works too. If they are missing while unpinned, you will need to reinstall the program.

Comment: every program in taskbar can not be unpinned and closed. Both "Close window" and "Unpin from taskbar" not work.